# Annoying css+div layout

Tags: css, xhtml, html

I've got a problem with a css+div layout. I need to set the background div to resize to left left, and keep the content position at the center.
Look at the picture:

[Layout div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyOEQ.jpg)

As you can see, I need to keep the space on the right fixed, but also the content needs to be centered, and the background needs to expand only to the left, is it possible at all?

Comment: If the left side has to shrink/grow, and the right side must have a fixed width; how can the content be centered then? One of these three requirements has to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've quickly made an example: http://jsfiddle.net/N73QA/

Let me know if You got any questions.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need this

```
#content{
 float:right;
 margin-right: 10px; /* or more */

 width: ......
}
```

that will keep your content to the right; the margin-right might need to be bigger then 10px to make it look centered

Comment: but when you change the resolution of the screen it won't be centered, is there any way to make it "auto" ?

Comment: I thought you had a fix size to your #bg_div - if the #bg_div has a fix size and floated to the left, then body width would not effect your design

Comment: you could achieve this (without the fix width to 'bg_div') with javascript

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand exactly (your question seems to conflict with the diagram), but can't you wrap everything in a div that's 50% screen width?

Style:

```css
#wrapper { width: 50%; }
#header, #bg, #footer { background: #46F; margin-bottom: 1em; }
#header { clear: both; float: right; height: 80px; width: 90%; }
#footer { clear: both; height: 80px; margin-top: 1em; }
#bg { clear: both; float: right; padding: 20px; width: 100%; }
#content { background: #ABF; clear: both; float: right; height: 400px; padding: 20px; width: 80%; }
```

Markup:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="bg">
        <div id="content">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sollicitudin sodales turpis et ultricies. Sed in enim ligula.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

The wrapper is 50% of the screen, while the content can be fixed or a percentage of that. Everything floats to the right within the wrapper.